# Можно ли в цикле переключаться с одного textView на другой?

Tags: циклы, android, textview

У меня есть 10 textView. И для этих 10 полей я создаю 10 переменных типа String. А можно ли все это занести в цикл, чтобы каждый новый текст был в каждом новом textView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865668/dynamically-change-a-variable-textview-id-in-android/30866027#30866027

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish, если вы переведёте своё сообщение и добавите его как ответ, то им сможет воспользоваться больше людей

Comment: так лучше не делать)

Comment: Думаю рефлексия при решении столь банальной задачи излишнее и неоправданное решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем если у вас в лэяуте получилась такая разметка:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"/>
```

Пожалуй самый лучший способ собрать все это в кучу и итерироваться, будет примерно такой:

```
List<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < textViewCount + 1; i++){
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
            TextView textViewItem = (TextView)findViewById(id);
            textViewItem.setTest("Новый текст" + i)
            textViewList.add(textViewItem);//кладем в колекцию если вы собираетесь еще раз менять текст
        }
```

Собирать в колекцию вьюшки не обязательно если действие одноразовое.
`textViewCount` можно захардкодить, но это тоже можно посчитать вызвав у контейнера метод `getChildCount()` если в контейнере есть другие вьюхи нужно в цикле пройти по дочерним методом `getChildAt(index)` и проверить `if(child instaceof TextView)`

а еще что бы не быть зависимым от `id` можно сделать так:

```
List<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = container.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof TextView){
                textViewList.add((TextView) child);
            }
        }
```

Мой ответ по ссылке делает тоже самое только через рефлекшен, при условии что все текстовые поля задекларированы в классе активити и проинициализированы.

Comment: Вы забыли, что нам надо засетить туда строки, а не в коллекцию упаковать. Если действие одноразовое, то логичнее при итерации сразу сетить, а не складывать для еще одной итерации. Правда автор ничего не сказал по этому поводу - из контекста я так понимаю, что действие одноразовое. А так да, пожалуй самое оптимальное, чтоб пройтись по кучке виджетов

Comment: Точняк. писал, писал а на вопрос не ответил) ща поправим

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>();
textViews.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1));
textViews.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2));
...

for(int i = 0; i < textViews.size(); i++) {
    textViews.get(i).setText(strings.get(i));
}
```

Comment: А ничего что у вас женерик типа TextView а вы пытаетесь засунуть тип View?:-)

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Кланяюсь перед повелителем Andoid. Обещаю в будущем исправиться!

Comment: Надеюсь он это видит)